# Capture/detect all runtime error in the program

Tags: android, runtime-error

In an Android application, whenever a runtime error occurs, is it possible to get its stack trace information and send this information to somewhere on the Internet? (by using code in that Android application or other methods)

I know this question looks a little weird because that Android application may already crashes when a runtime error occurs. But I still want to know whether this is possible.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this possible and also in couple of ways.
1) when ever an runtime error you can gather required error log and open mail application and send it to the desired person.
2) if you have any webservice then you can send the error log to desired place.

We have create a class which implements the UncaughtExceptionHandler and do it...

Answer (score 0):

> In an Android application, whenever a runtime error occurs, is it possible to get its stack trace information and send this information to somewhere on the Internet?

Yes. [ACRA](http://code.google.com/p/acra/) is perhaps the most popular example of this.